# Delete a file based on the value of the SelectedItem in a ListBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listbox

How do I delete a file in C# based on value from ListBox. This is my code, it's not working:

```
File.Delete( folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath+ "\" +listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
```

Comment: Is this a Windows Forms application?

Comment: Read the code you posted. You **remove** the selected item from the listbox, and then **try to use the selected item from the listbox**. It's not there - you *removed it*, remember?

Comment: What sort of error are you getting?  From first edit to now, I can see  a few things being wrong, but... it'd be nice to see what you get, so that we don't have to 100% spoon feed you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're getting a null exception.  You can't remove an item from the ListBox and then expect to be able to cast it to a string. **<-- that was relevant prior to your edit.**

Also, you're escaping your closing quotation mark with the backslash `"\"`. You should write it as `@"\"`, `"\\"`, `String.Format("{0}\{1}", path, fileName)`, or as `Path.Combine(path, fileName)`.

I, personally, prefer the later, due to the fact that I can avoid inserting slashes and make it look cleaner.

Beyond that, it's a good idea to have a `try{}catch{}` block around your IO code to catch any exceptions that may occur when attempting to delete a file.  If you're in a multi-user environment and someone else moves that files, opens it, etc., you'll get an exception unless your code accounts for it.

I also like to check if the selected item is null.  Personal preference.

```
if (listBox1.SelectedItem == null)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Selection is null");
    return;
}

try
{
    File.Delete(Path.Combine(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath,
                             listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()));
}
catch (System.IO.IOException e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

If you want to verify that a file exists, you may use:

```
if (File.Exists(Path.Combine(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath,                     
                             listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString())))
{
    // your code here
}
```

But it won't be necessary if you have a `try{}catch{}` block similar to the above.

In addition to the above, I'd like to add that I saw something interesting when you had your original code up.  You were deleting a file, removing an item from the selection box and then refreshing that selection box.  May I recommend using `ObservableCollection<T>()`?  Whenever you update this collection by adding or removing items, whatever is getting its items from this collection will receive the notification of the update.  In the case of the ListBox, it'll refresh on its own.

Comment: its saying that the file is used by another process so it cant be deleted

Comment: @OkwuPrecious What kind of file is it?

Comment: Thank you for all your answers. Its a txt file

Comment: @OkwuPrecious Hmm, I was hoping you'd say it's a Word document, then it'd be easy to figure out what's up (it's buggy).  Anyways, download this: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653 and find out which process has it open.  Deletion of a file that's open by another process is virtually impossible (well... it's possible, but it's incredibly hard and even with some of my x86 knowledge, I wouldn't be able to do it without tearing my hair out).  Use that neat program, it'll save you a lot of headache.  I, personally, have the entire utility suite from that site.

Comment: I think its because its in the listbox thats wats locking it

Comment: @OkwuPrecious Mmm... I don't see how it's possible.  ListBox only has its path, not the file itself.  Are you opening that file without closing it by any chance?  Make sure you do fileName.Close() if you open it.

Comment: @OkwuPrecious What are you stuck on?  You have to be specific. Here's what I would do.  1. Download the utility I recommended above.  2. Check which process has that txt file open.  3.  See if you can shutdown that process.  4. If it's your program, check to make sure that you're not opening that file within your program and then forgetting to close it.

Comment: I will do just that.Thank you very much.